# Need a constexpr for doubling value in for loop

Tags: c++, templates, constants, constexpr

I want to double a value each time a for loop is processed. I have the following code so far:

```
    constexpr size_t doubleN(size_t n, size_t iteration)
    {
        return n * iteration;
    };

    const array<size_t, 9> iterationArray = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 10 };
    for (size_t i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
    {
        Insertionsort<double, doubleN(INITIAL_SIZE_N_INSERTIONSORT, iterationArray[i])> insertionsort;
        Util<doubleN(INITIAL_SIZE_N_INSERTIONSORT, iterationArray[i])> util;
        array<double, doubleN(INITIAL_SIZE_N_INSERTIONSORT, iterationArray[i])> arrayRef;
        util.generateRandomDoubleArray(arrayRef);
        util.overwriteProcessorCache();

        cout << "Measure Insertionsort version 1 with n = " << INITIAL_SIZE_N_INSERTIONSORT << "." << endl;
        util.startTimeMeasure();
        insertionsort.sortVersion1(arrayRef);
        util.stopTimeMeasure();
        cout << "Measureing Insertionsort version 1 successful." << endl;
    }
```

My problem is, that I can't double the value returned by the `constexpr`, cause it always needs a constant value as parameter. Dou you have any idea how to get a `constexpr` that returns always a value which is doubled based on the prior doubled value?

Comment: `i` is a runtime variable, so you can't use it in a constant expression.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, turn your runtime `i` parameter into compile time value:

```
template <std::size_t I>
void foo()
{
    Insertionsort<double, doubleN(INITIAL_SIZE_N_INSERTIONSORT, I)> insertionsort;
    Util<doubleN(INITIAL_SIZE_N_INSERTIONSORT, I)> util;
    array<double, doubleN(INITIAL_SIZE_N_INSERTIONSORT, I)> arrayRef;
    util.generateRandomDoubleArray(arrayRef);
    util.overwriteProcessorCache();

    cout << "Measure Insertionsort version 1 with n = " << INITIAL_SIZE_N_INSERTIONSORT << "." << endl;
    util.startTimeMeasure();
    insertionsort.sortVersion1(arrayRef);
    util.stopTimeMeasure();
    cout << "Measureing Insertionsort version 1 successful." << endl;
}
```

then do a loop:

```
template <size_t ... Is>
void foos()
{
    int dummy[] = {0, (foo<Is>(), 0)...};
    (void) dummy; // avoid warning for unused variable
}
```

or with fold expression of C++17:

```
template <size_t ... Is>
void foos()
{
    (foo<Is>(), ...);
}
```

And call it:

```
foos<1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10>();
```